# Encapsulating and Disposing SqlClient Objects In Order

Tags: c#, sql-server, dispose, idisposable, sqlconnection

I am trying to layer my Sql client object calls such that they get disposed of reliably. Something like this:

> Open database connection -> Create command -> Read results -> close
>   command -> close database connection

So far this has succeeded when I do all of these things in the same method.

The problem is this is error prone. And a mess to read through.

When I try to create a common method to handle this that cleans up everything and returns a reader the connection gets closed before the reader starts.

```
//closes connection before it can be read...apparently the reader doesn't actually have any data at that point ... relocating to disposable class that closes on dispose
public SqlDataReader RunQuery(SqlCommand command)
{
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(_dbConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            command.Connection = dbConnection;

            reader = command.ExecuteReader();  // connection closed before data can be read by the calling method
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }

    return reader;
}
```

I can get around this by creating my own class that implements IDispose (etc) but then when I wrap it with the same using statement it takes up just as many lines as a database connection using statement.

How can I take care of the data base connection in a repeatable class that takes care of all these artifacts and closes the connection?

Comment: What kind of data are your trying to read? Can it be stored in a list or dictionary?

Comment: @KevinK.Yes I could. Sometimes I'm only returning 1 thing, but it could go in a list.

Comment: You should close the reader before connection is closed. So you should dispose all the objects after the data is received.

Comment: @Eugene : Thanks. That's what I suspected ... so there's no way to make a reusable method that tucks away all/most of the nested using statements?

Comment: I would design solution, which will read all the date inside and return data set. If it is not possible, you can try different approached to access the data. For example LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so there's no way to make a reusable method that tucks away all/most of the nested using statements?

There is a specific pattern supported for returning a DataReader from a method, like this:

```
static IDataReader GetData(string connectionString, string query)
{
    var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();
    var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    return rdr;
}
```

Then you can call this method in a `using` block:

```
    using (var rdr = GetData(constr, sql))
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            //process rows
        }
    } // <- the DataReader _and_ the connection will be closed here
```

Comment: Yes !! This is so trim and slim. Works great.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a class that holds an open database connection that is reusable, but I suggest reading the data into a list and returning the result:

```
public List<object> RunQuery(SqlCommand command)
{
    List<object> results = new List<object>();
    using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(_dbConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            command.Connection = dbConnection;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Repeat for however many columns you have
                    results.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

I don't know the structure of your data, but the important point is that you need to read your data (`reader.GetString` does this) before you dispose of the connection. You can find more information on how to properly read your data [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader).

Edit: As mentioned, I removed your `finally` statement. This is because your `using` statement is essentially doing the same thing. You can think of a `using` statement as a `try`-`finally` block. Your disposable object will always be disposed after the `using` statement is exited.

Comment: You have correctly removed the erroneous finally statement, but not mentioned that you did so, or why?